# Refraction coefficient for megahertz waves?

Tags: refraction

### Given

There are known refraction coefficients value for many materials, but for visible spectrum waves. I want to know refraction coefficient for megahertz radio waves, for example at 433 MHz.

According to [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5) ([related English article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_oscillator_model#Dielectric_function)), the refraction coefficient $n$ is described by the equation,
$$n = 1 + \dfrac{Nq^{2}_e}{2\varepsilon_0m_e(\omega^{2}_0-\omega^2)},$$
where $\omega_0$ is the resonance frequency of the material (a constant), and plain $\omega$ is frequency of the wave.

I assume that $N$ equals about $10^{24}$, and $\omega_0$, as stated on Wikipedia page I mentioned, for most materials is in ultraviolet specter  $\approx 10^{15}$Hz.

The $n(\omega)$ dependency is

[image]

### Problems

1. Do I understand correctly, that the lower frequency, the lower refraction coefficient (i.e., wave takes less time to travel through material)?
2. Is there table with actual values of refraction for megahertz waves, for materials, such as concrete, glass, etc.?

---

Possible answers:

[Concreter refraction at 57 Ghz wave](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/477526)

Comment: The charge $q_{e}$ is squared, so its sign doesn't matter.

Comment: @Buzz, right, updated